# Connecting output of module to another and looping this logic for a list of values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to connect 2 modules in vba such that the output of the first module (geturl) feeds into the other (getdata).

Get Url to look up the dossier URL online for substances entered in column A e.g. `Acetone` or alternatively the CAS number in column B can be used (see image below). Note: currently only looks up for substance info in A1 or B1.

```
Public Function GetUrl() As String
    
    Const Url = "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_javax.portlet.action=dissRegisteredSubstancesAction"
    
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    SubstanceName = Cells(1, 1)
    CASNumber = Cells(1, 2)
        
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_name") = SubstanceName
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_cas-number") = CASNumber
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"
    
    payload = vbNullString
        
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = IIf(Len(DictKey) = 0, WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)), _
                      payload & "&" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)))
    Next DictKey
        
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (payload)
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
        
    
    GetUrl = oHtml.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href")
    
    Debug.Print oHtml.querySelector(".substanceNameLink ").innerText
    Debug.Print oHtml.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href")
  
End Function
```

If run this should return
`Acetone  https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460`

Get Data uses the Url from geturl to return "DNEL" values:

```
Sub GetData()
        
'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument


Dim Route(1 To 3) As String

Route(1) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaInhalationRoute"
Route(2) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaDermalRoute"
Route(3) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaOralRoute"


XMLReq.Open "Get", GetUrl & "/7/1", False
XMLReq.send
 
If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub

    End If
 
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

'Loops through each element

For c = 1 To UBound(Route, 1)

Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(c))
Debug.Print Info.innerText

Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(c)).NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
Set Data = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")(0)
Debug.Print Data.innerText

Set Data = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")(1)
Debug.Print Data.innerText

'Cells(r, c + 2) = Data.innerText

Next c

End Sub
```

For Acetone in Cell(1,1) This should Return:

```
Acetone 
https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460
General Population - Hazard via inhalation route
DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
200 mg/m³
General Population - Hazard via dermal route
DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
62 mg/kg bw/day
General Population - Hazard via oral route
DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
62 mg/kg bw/day
```

Instead of just relying on Cell A1 however, I wish to have the entire code loop for each cell with a substance in columnA/ColumnB. So in this case the URL for Acetone is found and the corresponding data is then pulled then the same occurs for `Oxydipropanol`.

[image]

Note in this image Substances can be looked up online using either the substance name, CAS number in columnB, or a combination of both.

Trying to connect the two modules, zo far I have only been able to get the geturl module to cycle through for each substance. I have also tried to combine both into 1 module but cant figure out how to correctly nest the for loops.

A quick google search states that you cant nest functions in vba. This makes me wonder if what I'm doing is even the right way to approach this. But I've seen similar things achieved In the past so I'm sure it's possible.

Note: If testing please use the example substances for testing. Using a random chemical say Benzene may result in an error as the tox profile for this substance doesn't exist. I still need to implement handling errors but this can be ignored for now.

I Will update you here with any further progress made, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub PopulateExposures()
    Dim url, rw As Range
    
    Set rw = Sheets("data").Range("A1:E1") 'first row with inputs
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
        url = SubstanceUrl(rw.Cells(1).Value, rw.Cells(2).Value) 'get the URL
        rw.Cells(3).Resize(1, 3).Value = ExposureData(url) 'get exposure data (as array) and add to row
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next substance
    Loop

End Sub

Public Function SubstanceUrl(SubstanceName, CASNumber) As String
    
    Const url = "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?" & _
                "p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&" & _
                "p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&" & _
                "__dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_javax.portlet.action=dissRegisteredSubstancesAction"
    
    Dim oHTML, oHttp, MyDict, payload, DictKey, sep
    
    Set oHTML = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_name") = SubstanceName
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_cas-number") = CASNumber
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"
    
    payload = ""
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = payload & sep & DictKey & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey))
        sep = "&"
    Next DictKey
        
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send payload
        oHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    SubstanceUrl = oHTML.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href")
End Function

Function ExposureData(urlToGet)
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument, dds
    Dim Route(1 To 3) As String, Results(1 To 3) As String, c, Info, Data
    
    Route(1) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaInhalationRoute"
    Route(2) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaDermalRoute"
    Route(3) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaOralRoute"
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", urlToGet & "/7/1", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        Results(1) = "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Else
        Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
        For c = 1 To UBound(Route, 1)
            Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(c))
            If Not Info Is Nothing Then
                Set Info = Info.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
                Set dds = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")
                If dds.Length > 1 Then
                    Results(c) = dds(1).innerText
                Else
                    Results(c) = "hazard unknown"
                End If
            Else
                Results(c) = "no info"
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    ExposureData = Results
End Function
```

Comment: Amazing thank you so much

Comment: Do you know how I could add error handling to this code so that If I had a chemical name e.g. `Benzene`.  Just `-` is returned as the Exposure Data for the three columns? I just cant get the error handling to work within the for loops without it overwriting the results for substances that do work.

Comment: You mean benzene or any chemical which has no tox profile?

Comment: Added a few checks to the last function - you should get the general idea

Comment: Yeah any value with no Tox Profile. Benzene is just an example of this.